# Setting a value to a vector array value

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

Basically I want to set 5 strings to the value of 5 values within a vector array (sorry if that's hard to understand, new to C++) I want to set string card1 = deck[0], card2 = deck[1]… etc here's the code I have for this specific instance, I can always add more code from my project if that would help just ask and I will add it ASAP.

```
{   hand.push_back(deck[0]);
deck[0] == fcard;
fcard = card1;
hand.push_back(deck[1]);
deck[1] == scard;
scard = card2;
cout << card2;
}
```

Comment: I just noticed I  have "deck[0] == fcard" this is ONLY BECAUSE I TRIED IT WITH A SINGLE "=" and it didn't work, so I thought 'what the hell' this did not work either.

Comment: so "hand" is a vector, is deck also a vector?

Comment: PLease show all relevant code including class/member/variable declarations.  SHowing 1/2 of the puzzle is just more confusing.  "deck[1] == scard;" makes no sense.  "==" is a conditional operator that will return a Boolean result.

Comment: I really hate when people are so quick to say when someone is wrong, that they don't read the everything lol. I am quite aware of the "==" operator, thanks buddy! 

Josh, hand is vector but it had nothing to do with my question, it was answered already thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the thing you need is  as simple as what you explain, why didn't you do  :

```c
card1 = deck[0];
card2 = deck[1];
card3 = deck[2];
card4 = deck[3];
card5 = deck[4];
```

but maybe your pb is more complexe than that and more code will be helpfull :)

Comment: wow i'm kicking myself in the face right now. this did it. thank you wow